# PHP ForEach Array - display variables

Tags: php, curl

I have a Curl query which outputs JSON as `$response`

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

I have turned this into the below Array:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [jobId] => 41682277
                    [employerId] => 630007
                    [employerName] => ABC
                    [employerProfileId] => 
                    [employerProfileName] => 
                    [jobTitle] => Internal Sales Negotiator/Sales Executive
```

How can I loop through this array, to show each job on a website. I need to turn some of the fields into variables, for example, `jobTitle`

I have tried the below but nothing is output back;

```
foreach ($response as $job) {
    foreach ($job->results as $record) {
        $ID = $record->jobId;
        echo"JobID= $ID<br>";
        
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be because you turned the json into an associative array, but in your loop you use object notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your array structure, the following code snippet should do the trick. You decode your JSON payload as an associative array by adding the second argument of true to the [json_decode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), so it shouldn't being accessed as an object.

```
<?php

$response = [
    'results' => [
        [
            'jobId'               => 41682277,
            'employerId'          => 630007,
            'employerName'        => 'employerName',
            'employerProfileId'   => '',
            'employerProfileName' => 'employerProfileName',
            'jobTitle'            => 'Internal Sales Negotiator/Sales Executive',
        ],
    ],
];

foreach ($response['results'] as $record) {
    $id = $record['jobId'];
    echo "JobID = $id<br>";
}
```